# How get the height of Android navigation bar and status bar programmatically?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to get the size of the height of this UI element in pixels on Python?

Comment: Are you able to run tkinter on android? This question has the `tkinter` tag.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I able

Comment: Tkinter is meant to be a desktop GUI toolkit but if you insist to use it. You could do that and the right way to go would be with [pydroid 3](https://learning-python.com/using-tkinter-programs-on-android.html)